# GDAL Convert Format with PROJ string

Tags: gdal, convert, proj

I would like to perform the following transformation in the GDAL Convert Format tool in QGIS:

> > projinfo -s ETRF2000 -t ITRF2008 -o PROJ  Candidate operations found: 1  -------------------------------------  Operation n┬░1:
>
> unknown id, Conversion from ETRF2000 (geog2D) to ETRF2000 (geocentric)
>   + Inverse of ITRF2008 to ETRF2000 (1) + Conversion from ITRF2008 (geocentric) to ITRF2008 (geog2D), 0 m, Europe - ETRS89
>
> PROJ string:
>   +proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0521 +y=0.0493 +z=-0.0585 +rx=0.000891 +ry=0.00539 +rz=-0.008712 +s=0.00134 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0018 +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 +drz=-0.000792 +ds=8e-05 +t_epoch=2000 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

In the "Advanced Options" line, I wrote:

> -ct \ +proj=pipeline \
>   +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 \
>   +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad \
>   +step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \
>   +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0521 +y=0.0493 +z=-0.0585 +rx=0.000891 +ry=0.00539 \   +rz=-0.008712 +s=0.00134 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0018 +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 \   +drz=-0.000792 +ds=8e-05 +t_epoch=2000 +convention=position_vector \
>   +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \
>   +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

Unfortunately the operation is not performed and I get the following error:

> Algorithm 'Convert format' starting… Input parameters: { 'INPUT' :
>   'file:///C:/QGIS/Point_CRS/EPSG4258_survpoint.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4258&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no',
>   'OPTIONS' : '-ct \ +proj=pipeline \\n+step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
>   \\n+step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad \\n+step
>   +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \\n+step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0521 +y=0.0493 +z=-0.0585 +rx=0.000891 +ry=0.00539 \\n +rz=-0.008712 +s=0.00134 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0018 +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 \\n +drz=-0.000792 +ds=8e-05 +t_epoch=2000
>   +convention=position_vector \\n+step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \\n+step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step
>   +proj=axisswap +order=2,1', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/SK.HS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_506230c12af04d1e8de32b8b8457404b/f4219f0c381a406895aa93f6994c9eaf/OUTPUT.shp'
>   }
>
> GDAL command: ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -ct \ +proj=pipeline \
>   +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 \
>   +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad \
>   +step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \
>   +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0521 +y=0.0493 +z=-0.0585 +rx=0.000891 +ry=0.00539 \
>   +rz=-0.008712 +s=0.00134 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0018 +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 \
>   +drz=-0.000792 +ds=8e-05 +t_epoch=2000 +convention=position_vector \
>   +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 \
>   +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 C:/Users/SK.HS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_506230c12af04d1e8de32b8b8457404b/f4219f0c381a406895aa93f6994c9eaf/OUTPUT.shp
>   file:///C:/QGIS/Point_CRS/EPSG4258_survpoint.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=X&yField=Y&crs=EPSG:4258&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no
>   None GDAL command output: ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-ct'
>
> Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
>
> [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where|@filename]
>
> [-progress] [-sql |@filename] [-dialect dialect]
>
> [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID] [-limit nb_features]
>
> [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-spat_srs srs_def] [-geomfield field]
>
> [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
>
> [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
>
> dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
>
> [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name]
>
> [-nlt type|PROMOTE_TO_MULTI|CONVERT_TO_LINEAR|CONVERT_TO_CURVE]
>
> [-dim XY|XYZ|XYM|XYZM|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
>
> Advanced options :
>
> [-gt n] [-ds_transaction]
>
> [[-oo NAME=VALUE] ...] [[-doo NAME=VALUE] ...]
>
> [-clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource|spat_extent]
>
> [-clipsrcsql sql_statement] [-clipsrclayer layer]
>
> [-clipsrcwhere expression]
>
> [-clipdst [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource]
>
> [-clipdstsql sql_statement] [-clipdstlayer layer]
>
> [-clipdstwhere expression]
>
> [-wrapdateline][-datelineoffset val]
>
> [[-simplify tolerance] | [-segmentize max_dist]]
>
> [-addfields] [-unsetFid]
>
> [-relaxedFieldNameMatch] [-forceNullable] [-unsetDefault]
>
> [-fieldTypeToString All|(type1[,type2]*)] [-unsetFieldWidth]
>
> [-mapFieldType srctype|All=dsttype[,srctype2=dsttype2]*]
>
> [-fieldmap identity | index1[,index2]*]
>
> [-splitlistfields] [-maxsubfields val]
>
> [-explodecollections] [-zfield field_name]
>
> [-gcp ungeoref_x ungeoref_y georef_x georef_y [elevation]]* [-order n
>   | -tps]
>
> [-nomd] [-mo "META-TAG=VALUE"]* [-noNativeData]
>
> Note: ogr2ogr --long-usage for full help.
>
> Execution completed in 0.23 seconds Results: {'OUTPUT':
>   'C:/Users/SK.HS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_506230c12af04d1e8de32b8b8457404b/f4219f0c381a406895aa93f6994c9eaf/OUTPUT.shp'}
>
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - C:/Users/SK.HS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_506230c12af04d1e8de32b8b8457404b/f4219f0c381a406895aa93f6994c9eaf/OUTPUT.shp
>
> You
>   can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
>   information about the execution of the algorithm.

Obviously it seems to not find the '-ct' argument.....

I am running QGIS 3.4 Madeira on Windows...

I have not found example code for the "-ct" option..on the GDAL docs...

Can anybody take a look and suggest what I have to change?

Comment: What is the GDAL version that you are using? Check with `ogrinfo --version`. From QGIS you find the info from Help - About from the line "Compiled against GDAL/OGR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -ct parameter of ogr2ogr is used in the same way than all the other parameters that takes their value from a string. Just add -ct and then the string to use, enclosed between double quotes. As documented in https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html you need GDAL version 3.0 or higher for usint this option.

I tried you pipeline for the states.shp shapefile that is part of GeoServer test data and command runs without errors. I used GDAL version 3.1.0dev for testing.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test_with_ct.shp states.shp -ct " +proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0521 +y=0.0493 +z=-0.0585 +rx=0.000891 +ry=0.00539 +rz=-0.008712 +s=0.00134 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0018 +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 +drz=-0.000792 +ds=8e-05 +t_epoch=2000 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked flawlessly. Tried again with the latest QGIS version (3.10 A Coruna).